# Python Pillow - Facing issue with crop()

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-imaging-library

I am using jquery-cropper.js to crop an image on front end and then pass the values to Django form as shown below.

```
def save(self):
    photo = super(MyModelForm, self).save()

    x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
    y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
    w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
    h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')


    image = Image.open(photo.profile_pic)

    cropped_image = image.crop((int(x), int(y), int(w+x), int(h+y)))
    cropped_image.save(photo.profile_pic.path)

    #resized_image = cropped_image.resize((min(new_width, new_height), min(new_width, new_height)), Image.LANCZOS)
    #resized_image.save(photo.profile_pic.path)

    return photo
```

The issue at the moment is that image is cropped fine on the front end but not on the backend. I get  black area in the cropped pic. I want exact image as I see on the front end. The coordinates on the front end and backend are same.

The cropped image is like [image: this]

Answer (score 0):

Finally after spending hours trying to fix this I found the cause.

the `save()` method is called twice when the form is submitted. This causes the `crop()` method to run twice and ruins the image. Right now I am using a flag to keep track of if the `crop()` was already called once.

```
cropFlag = 0

def save(self):
photo = super(MyModelForm, self).save()
if self.cropFlag == 0:
    x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
    y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
    w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
    h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')


   image = Image.open(photo.profile_pic)

   cropped_image = image.crop((int(x), int(y), int(w+x), int(h+y)))
   cropped_image.save(photo.profile_pic.path)

   self.cropFlag = self.cropFlag + 1

return photo
```

If anyone has better idea please do comment.

Cheers.